# ReactJS Website Re-Rendering and Flashing on Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, mobile, use-effect

I made an app that uses ReactJS and Firebase storage deployed on GitHub pages. Currently, the website is flashing and re-rendering on the homepage (RealHome.jsx). I am wondering what is causing this problem. I have suspicions that it is the use of the useEffect(). Does anyone know the problem or have fixed this problem before?

Github Repo: github.com/joshuajy03/purduebikesintrees

Website: joshuajy03.github.io/purduebikesintrees

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem

Comment: @hisam it seems that I fixed the problem by removing the window.addEventListener

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the website was that I was using window.addEventListener.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", () => setResponsiveness());

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", () => setResponsiveness());
    };
```

Removing this solves the problem.